# Initializing Constant Static Array In Header File

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, header-files

I have just found out that the following is not valid.

```
//Header File
class test
{
    const static char array[] = { '1', '2', '3' };
};
```

Where is the best place to initialize this?

Answer (score 57):

The best place would be in a source file

```
// Header file
class test
{
    const static char array[];
};

// Source file
const char test::array[] = {'1','2','3'};
```

You can initialize integer types in the class declaration like you tried to do; all other types have to be initialized outside the class declaration, and only once.

Comment: Shouldn't that say "... in the class *declaration*..."? I thought `.h` were declarations and `.c` were definitions, hence why taking a reference to an integer type that is declared only in the header results in a compiler error: `undefined reference to test::SOME_INTEGER`? (I realize this sounds super nit-picky and pedantic, and I'm not trying to be difficult; I just want to make sure I'm using the right terminology, so definitely correct me if I'm wrong).

Answer (score 38):

You can always do the following:

```
class test {
  static const char array(int index) {
    static const char a[] = {'1','2','3'};
    return a[index];
  } 
};
```

A couple nice things about this paradigm:

- No need for a cpp file
- You can do range checking if you want to
- You avoid having to worry about the [static initialization fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order)

Comment: I couldn't get the compiler to have then `&a[1]` be consistent over multiple objects.

Comment: For string literals, this is perfect!

Comment: Your link "static initialization fiasco" is dead.

Comment: it uses lock to access the a[]

Comment: @sergiol fixed the dead link (three years later)

Answer (score 21):

```
//Header File 
class test 
{ 
    const static char array[];
}; 

// .cpp
const char test::array[] = { '1', '2', '3' };
```

Comment: Thanks, was not sure if you could do this out side of a member.

Comment: No static in the definition, please.

Comment: Because they didn't try to compile it. ^_-  Seriously, though, `static`'s many uses confuse a lot of folks.

Comment: oops - sorry, That was a copy-and-paste-o, fixed.

Answer (score 13):

Now, in C++17, you can use **inline variable**

[How do inline variables work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043442/what-is-an-inline-variable-and-what-is-it-useful-for)

> A simple static data member([N4424](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4424.pdf)):
>
> ```
> struct WithStaticDataMember {
>   // This is a definition, no out­of­line definition is required.
>   static inline constexpr const char *kFoo = "foo bar";
> };
> ```

In your example:

```
//Header File
class test
{
    inline constexpr static char array[] = { '1', '2', '3' };
};
```

should just work

Comment: `static constexpr` already implies `inline` I believe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391272/does-constexpr-imply-inline/57407675#57407675

Comment: I found this answer super useful! Using inline also allows you to have access to the length of the array just by including the header. But `constexpr` is not needed. The whole point of `inline` is being able to define the values without `constexpr`. https://godbolt.org/z/f94e73dav

Answer (score 2):

**With `constexpr` you must define the value on the header even in C++11**

If you use `constexpr` instead of `const`, then [this answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14395967/proper-initialization-of-static-constexpr-array-in-class-template/14396189#14396189) that you not only can, but must, define on header [even in C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40959093/895245):

```
#include <cassert>

struct MyClass {
    static constexpr int is[] = {1, 2, 3};
    static constexpr int i = 1;
};

// TODO is this ever mandatory? Create example that fails on -std=c++11.
// Pretty sure never mandatory in C++17 https://stackoverflow.com/a/40959093/895245
// constexpr int MyClass::is[];

int main (void) {
    assert(MyClass::is[0] == 1);
    assert(&MyClass::is[0] == &MyClass::is[1] - 1);
    assert(MyClass::i == 1);
    assert(&MyClass::i == &MyClass::i);
}
```

Compile and run with:

```
g++-10 -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o main.out main.cpp
./main.out
```

If instead you try:

```
struct MyClass {
    static constexpr int is[];
};

constexpr int MyClass::is[] = {1, 2, 3};
```

compilation fails with:

```
main.cpp:4:26: error: ‘constexpr’ static data member ‘is’ must have an initializer
```

Tested on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of an abuse of the system, but if you REALLY want to define it in the header file (and you don't have C++17), you can do this. It won't be a static member, but it will be a constant that only takes up storage per compilation unit (rather than per class instance):

(Put all of this code in the header file.)

```
namespace {
    const char test_init_array[] = {'1', '2', '3'};
}

class test {
public:
    const char * const array;

    test() : array(test_init_array) {}
};
```