# Is there a way to have array behavior as static struct data member?

Tags: c++, templates, static-members

I have a mechanism like the following for retrieving certain parameters for a limited number of different types of objects I need to handle:

```
template <class T>
struct params {};

template <>
struct params<FooObj>
{
    static const int paramA = 17;
    static const int paramB = 29;
};
```

this simplifies my code later because in a switch statement when I handle treating different objects, if I get a `FooObj` then all I have to do is something like this:

```
typedef params<FooObj> paramsT;
```

and then in that code snippet I have access to parameters to work with that `FooObj` via `paramsT::paramC` or whatever.

Now I have run into an object where I have something like this:

```
template <>
struct params<BarObj>
{
    static const int paramA  = 0;
    static const int paramB  = 9;
    static const int paramC  = 17;
    static const int paramD1 = 18;
    static const int paramE1 = 20;
    static const int paramD2 = 28;
    static const int paramE2 = 30;
    static const int paramD3 = 38;
    static const int paramE3 = 40;
    static const int paramD4 = 48;
    static const int paramE4 = 50;
    static const int paramD5 = 58;
    static const int paramE5 = 60;
    static const int paramD6 = 68;
    static const int paramE6 = 70;
};
```

and when I'm handling this object I started writing something like the following:

```
typedef params<BarObj> paramsT;
BarObj bar;
//load the first 3 params via the above info into bar

int a,b;
for (int i = 1; i <= 6; ++i)
{
    a = doSomethingA(bla + paramsT::paramD1);
    b = doSomethingB(bla + paramsT::paramE1);
    bla.paramD1 = functionOf(stuff,and,a,b);
}
```

but of course the above has `1` hardcoded into it, and it would ideally read something like this:

```
typedef params<BarObj> paramsT;
BarObj bar;
//load the first 3 params via the above info into bar

int a,b;
for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
{
    a = doSomethingA(bla + paramsT::paramD[i]);
    b = doSomethingB(bla + paramsT::paramE[i]);
    bla.paramD[i] = functionOf(stuff,and,a,b);
}
```

although for something like the above I would need the params template specialization to be something like this:

```
template <>
struct params<BarObj>
{
    static const int paramA   = 0;
    static const int paramB   = 9;
    static const int paramC   = 17;
    static const int paramD[] = {18, etc..};
    static const int paramE[] = {20, etc..};
};
```

which doesn't compile because the arrays even though hardcoded are non-integral types. Is there an easy patch around this that wouln't hopefully look too different from my current usage? Or a way to get that array stuff in there?

Comment: Why are you using templated structs to hold hardcoded values instead of just a simple table of values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "static implicitly inline function static local variable" hack:

```
template<typename T>
struct params;
struct Bob;
template<>
struct params<Bob> {
  static int paramE(unsigned int idx) {
    static const int v[] = {18, 20, 22, 24};
    return v[idx];
  }
};

#include <iostream>
int main() {
  for(auto i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    std::cout << params<Bob>::paramE(i) << "\n";
}
```

note that the resulting values are not "compile time constants" (ie, cannot be used for things like template parameters), but are trivial for compilers to optimize into constants.

Comment: This is a cleaner solution than mine, as long as you don't mind calling a function ( () syntax ) over an index ( [] syntax )

Comment: This is awesome, I definitely like this.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* initialize static const arrays, just not inside the class, as in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117313/initializing-constant-static-array-in-header-file). The challenge is that you have to do the initialization exactly once per compilation unit, so it's most often done in source (.cpp) files, - therefore, it will be far away from the rest of your initialization, which is fairly gross.

Comment: Yes I started doing this but I agree it's fairly gross.