# Does constexpr imply inline?

Tags: c++, c++11, inline, standards-compliance, constexpr

Consider the following inlined function :

```
// Inline specifier version
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>

inline int f(const int x);

inline int f(const int x)
{
    return 2*x;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    return f(std::atoi(argv[1]));
}
```

and the constexpr equivalent version :

```
// Constexpr specifier version
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>

constexpr int f(const int x);

constexpr int f(const int x)
{
    return 2*x;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    return f(std::atoi(argv[1]));
}
```

My question is : does the `constexpr` specifier imply the `inline` specifier in the sense that if a non-constant argument is passed to a `constexpr` function, the compiler will try to `inline` the function as if the `inline` specifier was put in its declaration ?

Does the C++11 standard guarantee that ?

Comment: '[Will] the compiler try to inline the function' is not what the `inline` specifier does. (Or maybe I misunderstood your phrasing.)

Comment: The `inline` specifier no longer has anything to do with _inlining_

Comment: The question foots on the wrong assumption that `inline` is directly related to inlining. So no, the `constexpr` specifier doesn't imply the `inline` specifier in that sense, as *that* sense doesn't exist.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Yes ([dcl.constexpr], §7.1.5/2 in the C++11 standard): "constexpr functions and constexpr constructors are implicitly inline (7.1.2)."

Note, however, that the `inline` specifier really has *very* little (if any) effect upon whether a compiler is likely to expand a function inline or not. It does, however, affect the one definition rule, and from that perspective, the compiler is required to follow the same rules for a `constexpr` function as an `inline` function.

I should also add that regardless of `constexpr` implying `inline`, the rules for `constexpr` functions in C++11 required them to be simple enough that they were often good candidates for inline expansion (the primary exception being those that are recursive). Since then, however, the rules have gotten progressively looser, so `constexpr` can be applied to substantially larger, more complex functions.

Comment: Given that the idea is that constant expressions are evaluated at compile time, I suppose most uses of `constexpr` functions won't cause any code generation at all...

Comment: @KerrekSB `constexpr` functions are potentially evaluated at compile time. However the C++14 standard is littered with ones which will very likely be called at runtime. For example: `std::array<T,N>::at`

Comment: @Eponymous yes but only the most-reduced form will remain as opcodes though. e.g: the bound checks, will be evaluated at build time, since their code path is const. But the returned value will be *(data+offset)

Comment: I suggest editing this to clarify that it's no longer necessarily the case as of C++17 as per the answer below this one. See https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0386r2.pdf

Answer (score 77):

**`constexpr` does not imply `inline` for non-static variables (C++17 inline variables)**

While `constexpr` does imply `inline` for functions, it does not have that effect for non-static variables, considering C++17 inline variables.

For example, if you take the minimal example I posted at: [How do inline variables work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043442/how-do-inline-variables-work/53896763#53896763) and remove the `inline`, leaving just `constexpr`, then the variable gets multiple addresses, which is the main thing inline variables avoid.

`constexpr` static variables are however implicitly inline.

**Minimal example that `constexpr` implies `inline` for functions**

As mentioned at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14391320/895245 the main effect of `inline` is not to inline but to allow multiple definitions of a function, standard quote at: [How can a C++ header file include implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517546/how-can-a-c-header-file-include-implementation/57406630#57406630)

We can observe that by playing with the following example:

main.cpp

```
#include <cassert>

#include "notmain.hpp"

int main() {
    assert(shared_func() == notmain_func());
}
```

notmain.hpp

```
#ifndef NOTMAIN_HPP
#define NOTMAIN_HPP

inline int shared_func() { return 42; }
int notmain_func();

#endif
```

notmain.cpp

```
#include "notmain.hpp"

int notmain_func() {
    return shared_func();
}
```

Compile and run:

```
g++ -c -ggdb3  -O0 -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 -pedantic-errors  -o 'notmain.o' 'notmain.cpp' 
g++ -c -ggdb3  -O0 -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 -pedantic-errors  -o 'main.o' 'main.cpp' 
g++ -ggdb3  -O0 -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 -pedantic-errors  -o 'main.out' notmain.o main.o
./main.out
```

If we remove `inline` from `shared_func`, link would fail with:

```
multiple definition of `shared_func()'
```

because the header gets included into multiple `.cpp` files.

But if we replace `inline` with `constexpr`, then it works again, because `constexpr` also implies `inline`.

GCC implements that by marking the symbols as weak on the ELF object files: [How can a C++ header file include implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517546/how-can-a-c-header-file-include-implementation/57406630#57406630)

Tested in GCC 8.3.0.

Comment: BTW, a static class member variable declared `constexpr` is still inline. [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline): _A static member variable (but not a namespace-scope variable) declared `constexpr` is implicitly an inline variable._

Comment: @anton_rh thanks, I hadn't seen that rule, update answer.

Comment: it's not what http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0386r0.pdf says. it says constexpr implies inline for variables. with no mention of a difference between namespace scope of class scope.

Comment: >BTW, a static class member variable declared constexpr is still inline. cppreference.com: A static member variable (but not a namespace-scope variable) declared constexpr is implicitly an inline variable.

Just to add, it is only since C+17.

Comment: @ciro-santilli-trump-ban-is-bad If you have a chance, can you correct your statement "constexpr static variables are however implicitly static."?  I assume one of those words "static" was meant to be "inline".

Comment: A sid question: is `#ifndef` - `#define` a recommended pattern over `#pragma once`?

Comment: @SohailSi see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143936/pragma-once-vs-include-guards

Comment: @v.oddou No but it is what https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0386r2.pdf says.

`The ​constexpr​ specifier implies ​ inline only for static data members, not also for namespacescope variables.`