# Undefined symbols for constexpr function

Tags: c++, c++11, linker-errors, constexpr

When I attempt compiling the following code I get a linker error: `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "Foo()", referenced from: _main in main.o` using LLVM 4.2.

This behavior only occurs when the function is marked `constexpr`. The program compiles and links correctly when the function is marked `const`. Why does declaring the function `constexpr` cause a linker error?

(I realize that writing the function this way doesn't give the benefit of compile-time computation; at this point I am curious why the function fails to link.)

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test.hpp"

int main()
{
    int bar = Foo();
    std::cout << bar << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**test.hpp**

```
constexpr int Foo();
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include "test.hpp"

constexpr int Foo()
{
    return 42;
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391272/does-constexpr-imply-inline

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Why does declaring the function `constexpr` cause a linker error?

That is because `constexpr` functions are implicitly `inline`. Per Paragraph 7.1.5/2 of the C++11 Standard:

> A `constexpr` specifier used in the declaration of a function that is not a constructor declares that function
>   to be a `constexpr` function. Similarly, a `constexpr` specifier used in a constructor declaration declares that
>   constructor to be a `constexpr` constructor. **`constexpr` functions and `constexpr` constructors are implicitly
>   `inline` (7.1.2).**

Per Paragraph 7.1.2/4, then:

> An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used and shall have exactly
>   the same definition in every case (3.2). [...]

Comment: `inline` doesn't have any effect on linkage.  (It's likely that `constexpr` does, given its relationship with const in general, but there's nothing in the section that you quote which would indicate this.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: 7.1.5 says "The `constexpr` specifier has no eﬀect on the type of a constexpr function or a constexpr constructor." and (language) linkage is part of a function's type (7.5).  So that would seem to restrict any effect of `constexpr` on linkage.

Comment: @BenVoigt language linkage (`extern "C"`/`extern "C++"` etc.) and linkage (external/internal/no linkage) are completely different things. That said, `constexpr` doesn't affect the linkage of functions; it may affect the linkage of objects (due the the implicit `const`).

Answer (score 11):

The body of a `constexpr` function must be visible at every point where it's used. In your case you have to `move Foo()`'s code to `test.hpp`.

For instance, consider this code in `main.cpp`:

```
constexpr int Foo(); 

int main() {
  static_assert(Foo() == 42, "Ops");
}
```

where `Foo()` is defined in `test.cpp`. How the compiler is supposed to check the `static_assert` condition while processing `main.cpp` if it cannot see that `Foo()` does return `42`. That's impossible. The whole point of `constexpr` functions is that the compiler can "call" them at compile time and for this to happen it must see the code.

Therefore, this compiles fine:

```
constexpr int Foo() { return 42; }

int main() {
  static_assert(Foo() == 42, "Ops");
}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for mentioning `static_assert`. That makes the cause of my problem much more obvious.

Answer (score 1):

It's an interesting question.  As Andy Prowl, `constexpr` makes
the function `inline`, which means that there must be
a definition of it in every translation unit which uses it;
I would have expected an error from the compiler.  (Actually, if
I read §3.2/5 correctly, a diagnostic is required if you use the
function and there is no definition.)

As to why `const` has different behavior: you can't mark
a non-menber function `const`.  If you write `const int Foo();`,
it is not the function which is `const`, but the type it returns
(except that if the return type is not a class type,
cv-qualifiers are ignored, so this is really the same as `int
Foo();`).