# Why does the compiler complain about undefined reference to a constexpr function even though it is defined in another source file?

Tags: c++, c++11, constants

I have source code in two files.

The first file contains `int main()` function and declaration and usage of `constexpr int square(int x)` function.

```
// File: foo.cpp
#include <iostream>

constexpr int square(int x);

int main()
{
    int a = square(10);
    std::cout << "a: " << a << "\n";
}
```

The second file contains the definition of `constexpr int square(int x)` function.

```
// File: bar.cpp
constexpr int square(int x)
{
    return x * x;
}
```

When I try to compile these two files, I get the following error.

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 bar.cpp foo.cpp
foo.cpp:4:15: warning: inline function ‘constexpr int square(int)’ used but never defined
 constexpr int square(int x);
               ^
/tmp/cc7iwVDZ.o: In function `main':
foo.cpp:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `square(int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I remove the `constexpr` keyword from both source files, then the program compiles and runs fine.

```
$ sed 's/constexpr//g' foo.cpp > foo2.cpp
$ sed 's/constexpr//g' bar.cpp > bar2.cpp
$ g++ -std=c++11 bar2.cpp foo2.cpp
$ ./a.out 
a: 100
```

Why does the program not compile when the `constexpr` keyword is present? Why does it complain about undefined reference to `square(int)` when it is clearly present in 'bar.cpp' specified as command line argument to g++?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14391272/1601448 because a constexpr function is implicitly inline, it is impossible to link to it. It needs to be available when compiling the c++ file (which makes sense)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the compiler can do so, it will replace a call to a `constexpr` function with its resulting value. As a result, `constexpr` functions are implicitly `inline`.

Normally you should define `constexpr` functions in headers.