# Does template function declared constexpr allways inline even if instantiation is not constexpr?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, inline, constexpr

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14391320/5632316) constexpr function are always `inline`.

A template function can be declared `constexpr` even if all specialization does not fulfill the requirements to be a `constexpr` function. In this last case, the specialization is not `constexpr`.

For example:

```
template<class T>
constexpr decltype(auto) size(const T& a){
   return a.size();
}
std::array<int,10> arr;
std::vector<int> vec;
size(arr);//constexpr
size(vec);//not a constexpr;
```

The instantiation `size<std::vector>` is not `constexpr`, but is it `inline`?

Comment: I suspect it still bears the implicit `inline` specifier. However, it's still up to the compiler to actually `inline` it, with the special case of making it possible to have multiple definitions in various translation units

Comment: Consider adding a `language-lawyer` tag

Comment: "Since C++17 a template function can be declared constexpr even if all specialization does not fulfill the requirements to be a constexpr function." That's been the case since C++11.

Comment: OK, I correct it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes; citing N4640, [dcl.constexpr]/1:

> … A function or static data member declared with the `constexpr` specifier is implicitly an inline function or variable. …

The key here is "*declared with*" – the declaration is what matters, not the satisfaction of `constexpr` requirements.