# Does constepxr imply inline

Tags: c++, c++17, inline, constexpr

If found the following code snippet on cppreference:

```
inline constexpr std::size_t dynamic_extent = std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max();
```

I thought constepxr implies inline.

- Is there any value in marking a variable as constexpr and inline?

I found different sources giving different answers. Some say yes. Others say no. I'm confused.

[Does constexpr imply inline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391272/does-constexpr-imply-inline) does not clearly answers my question. Because the related answer saying no has a comment saying yes. I found other sources saying yes, too. But cppreference still uses both.

Comment: Hm the former question appears to ask about inline functions, whereas this is asking about variables. I agree also that the answer there which says "no" also has a comment saying "yes". Overall I left that question not actually knowing with 100% certainty.

Comment: " A constexpr specifier used in a function or static member variable (since C++17) declaration implies inline". So the answer is no.