# First constexpr std::array variable (with deduced template parameters from initializer list) results in error: 'variable' defined but not used

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr, gcc-warning, stdarray

I have a header file containing multiple constexpr variables like the following:

```
namespace AAA {
constexpr const char* A = "abc";
constexpr std::array B = {"aaa", "bbb"};
}

namespace BBB {
constexpr const char* C = "def";
constexpr std::array D = {"ccc", "ddd"};
constexpr const char* E = "efg";
}
```

This header is used in multiple projects (separate parts of the code). When trying to build, I get something like:
`error: 'AAA::B' defined but not used.`

I do not get the error for `BBB::D`, although neither of the variables are used in the translation units that yield the error.

If I change the third line to

```
constexpr std::array<const char*, 2> B = {"aaa", "bbb"};
```

compilation goes through (although I have not changed `constexpr std::array D = {"ccc", "ddd"};`).

Adding `static` keyword does not affect the outcome. Adding template parameters for `BBB::D` and not adding it for `AAA::B` does not help either.

Any ideas what the reason is?

Comment: Whereas gcc only warns for first unused `constexpr array` (i.e commenting `B` results in warning for `D`), clang warns for all of those constexpr variables [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/q5h8vqjxW).

Comment: BTW, you got error as you treat warning as error.

Comment: Making all of the variables `inline` gets it to compile on all of the compilers in Jarod's link.  You really should be doing that anyways with variables defined in a header file.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is very helpful. The remaining question is why adding template parameters to std::array (i.e. <const char*, 2>) avoids the warning.

And by the way, why does it complain about AAA::B, and not AAA::A in the first place?
Could it have something to do with the std::array being a class and char* being a primitive type?

Comment: @NathanOliver, `consexpr` should imply `inline` for static variables, but as mentioned adding `static` keyword (or `inline`) does not help in my real use case. (why? :-| )

Please see the 2nd answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391272/does-constexpr-imply-inline

Comment: @KMot `inline` for static variables only applies to class member static variables.  Non-class member statics  do not get that and must explicitly be declared inline.

Comment: *"why does it complain about `AAA::B`, and not `AAA::A` in the first place?"* Clang does. Maybe gcc just ignores "trivial" types.