# Proper initialization of static constexpr array in class template?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, static-members, constexpr

Static class members in C++ have caused a little confusion for me due to the standard's verbiage:

> *9.4.2  Static data members* **[class.static.data]**
>
> The declaration of a static data member in its class definition is not a  definition...

However a *constexpr* is required to be initialized (AFAIK, couldn't find a quote from the standard) at its declaration (e.g., in the class definition).

Because of the restrictions on constexpr I had actually forgotten about the requisite for static members to be defined outside of the class, until I tried accessing a static constexpr array. [This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016780/undefined-reference-to-static-constexpr-char) provides the correct way of defining the array member, but I'm interested as to the implications on this definition in a class template.

This is what I ended up with:

```
template<typename T>
class MyClass
{
private:
  static constexpr std::size_t _lut[256] = { /* ... */ };
  T _data;

public:
  static constexpr std::size_t GetValue(std::size_t n) noexcept
  {
    return _lut[n & 255];
  }

  // ...
};

template<typename T>
constexpr std::size_t MyClass<T>::_lut[256];
```

**Is this the right syntax?** Particularly the use of template in the definition feels awkward, but GCC seems to be linking everything appropriately.

As a follow-up question, should non-array static constexpr members be similarly defined (with template definition outside of class)?

Comment: One confusing thing here: The declaration in the class is not a definition but has an initializer.  The declaration outside the class has no initializer but is a definition.

Comment: It is confusing (at least IMHO), but the constexpr specification requires the initializer to be at the point of declaration, not the point of definition. Presumably this is in relation to the way constant expressions are handled in terms of ODR (that is a constexpr member isn't required to have a definition so long as it is only used in compile-time constant expressions - see the answer ecatmur gave).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you want 9.4.2p3:

> If a non-volatile `const static` data member is of integral or enumeration type, its declaration in the class definition can specify a *brace-or-equal-initializer* in which every *initializer-clause* that is an *assignment-expression* is a constant expression (5.19). A static data member of literal type can be declared in the class definition with the `constexpr` specifier; if so, its declaration shall specify a *brace-or-equal-initializer* in which every *initializer-clause* that is an *assignment-expression* is a constant expression. [...] The member shall still be defined in a namespace scope if it is odr-used (3.2) in the program and the namespace scope definition shall not contain an *initializer*.

The definition of a *template* static data member is a *template-declaration* (14p1).  The example given in 14.5.1.3p1 is:

```
template<class T> class X {
  static T s;
};
template<class T> T X<T>::s = 0;
```

However, as above a `constexpr static` or `const static` member whose in-class declaration specifies an *initializer* should not have an *initializer* in its namespace scope definition, so the syntax becomes:

```
template<class T> class X {
  const static T s = 0;
};
template<class T> T X<T>::s;
```

The difference with the non-array (i.e. integral or enumeration) static constexpr data member is that its use in lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is not odr-use; you would only need to define it if taking its address or forming a const reference to it.

Comment: Thanks! The edit has some useful additions! :) Regarding the non-array members, you're saying that since it is a constexpr the member doesn't actually have to be defined (so long as it is indeed a constant expression, and being used in the context of such)?

Comment: @monkey_05_06 precisely; 3.2p3 says that odr-use of a variable `x` occurs *unless* `x` "satisfies the requirements for appearing in a constant expression", i.e. it is integral `const` or literal `constexpr`.

Comment: It would be good to provide an example that fails to compile if the `template<class T> T X<T>::s;` is omitted, ODR burning my brain, e.g. starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63613408/895245

Answer (score 15):

In case it helps anyone out, the following worked for me with GCC 4.7 using constexpr:

```
template<class T> class X {
  constexpr static int s = 0;
};
template<class T> constexpr int X<T>::s; // link error if this line is omitted
```

I'm not making any claims of whether this is "proper".  I'll leave that to those more qualified.

Comment: I needed this with a constexpr struct.